# Возможно ли прервать асинхронный запрос в JS

Tags: javascript, requests, fetch, асинхронность

Всем привет,
Решил написать страницу для генераций "отчёта", на данный момент на странице присутствует 2 `input` с типом `date` и `button` при нажатие на выполняется n количество асинхронных запросов к `php` файлу для получение данных в соответствие с количествами неделями между датами.
Но есть такая проблема что если пользователь выбрал неправильную дату и хочет отменить генерацию отчёта, то ему надо перезагрузить страницу.

Так вот мой вопрос: Возможно ли в JavaScript отменить выполнения асинхронного запроса?

Часть кода:

```js
const dateStart = document.getElementById('date-start');
const dateEnd = document.getElementById('date-end');
const button = document.getElementById('generate-report');

async function getData(params) {
  let response = await fetch('index.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(params)
  });

  try {
    return response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error => ' + error);
  }
  return null;
}

function returnStringFromDate(date) {
  return date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0') + '-' + date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
}

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let start = new Date(dateStart.value);
  let end = new Date(dateEnd.value);
  let dateDiff = (end - start) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;

  while (dateDiff > 7) {
    let endTemp = returnStringFromDate(end);
    end.setDate(end.getDate() - 7);
    let startTemp = returnStringFromDate(end);

    getData({
      resource: 'time',
      filter: {
        datebegin: start,
        dateend: end
      }
    }).then(response => {
      generateReport(response);
    });
    dateDiff -= 7;
  }

  if (dateDiff > 0 || dateStartString === dateEndString) {
    let endTemp = returnStringFromDate(end);
    end.setDate(end.getDate() - dateDiff);
    let startTemp = returnStringFromDate(end);
    getData({
      resource: 'time',
      filter: {
        datebegin: start,
        dateend: end
      }
    }).then(response => {
      generateReport(response);
    });
  }
})

function generateReport() {
  console.log('generate');
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="date-start">
<input type="date" id="date-end">
<button id="generate-report">Сгенерировать отчёт</button>
```

Comment: Вроде бы если послать к пыхе ещё один запрос, то предыдущий прервётся.... это можно увидеть в Network браузера..... вот вопрос больше в том, что будет происходить на сервере, прервётся ли например SQL запрос в БД

Comment: если на сервере не установлено ignore_user_abort то выполнение прервётся при закрытии первого соединения никакой проблемы не произойдёт

Comment: зачем временной интервал разбивать на отрезки и посылать серверу тысячи однотипных запросов представьте что я выберу интервал в несколько тысячелетий ваш сервер умрёт. Представьте бассейн наполненный разноцветными шариками и вам нужно выбрать синие и красные как быстрее выьирать сразу оба цвета или сначала выбрать один а потом заного начать выбирать второй и что если цветов больше

Comment: Саму асинхронную операцию прервать нельзя, однако можно эмулировать завершение операции и прервать цепочку вызовов. Ограничение - текущая выполняемая операция будет выполнена.

Answer (score 0):

Можно вынести переменную dateDiff за рамки функции и например обнулить это остановит цепочку запросов

```js
const dateStart = document.getElementById('date-start');
const dateEnd = document.getElementById('date-end');
const button = document.getElementById('generate-report');
const cancl = document.getElementById('cancel');

let dateDiff;

async function getData(params) {
  let response = await fetch('index.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(params)
  });

  try {
    return response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error => ' + error);
  }
  return null;
}

function returnStringFromDate(date) {
  return date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0') + '-' + date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
}

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  button.classList.toggle("h");
  cancl.classList.toggle("h");

  let start = new Date(dateStart.value);
  let end = new Date(dateEnd.value);
  dateDiff = (end - start) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;

  while (dateDiff > 7) {
    let endTemp = returnStringFromDate(end);
    end.setDate(end.getDate() - 7);
    let startTemp = returnStringFromDate(end);

    getData({
      resource: 'time',
      filter: {
        datebegin: start,
        dateend: end
      }
    }).then(response => {
      generateReport(response);
    });
    dateDiff -= 7;
  }

  if (dateDiff > 0 || dateStartString === dateEndString) {
    let endTemp = returnStringFromDate(end);
    end.setDate(end.getDate() - dateDiff);
    let startTemp = returnStringFromDate(end);
    getData({
      resource: 'time',
      filter: {
        datebegin: start,
        dateend: end
      }
    }).then(response => {
      generateReport(response);
    });
  }
})

function generateReport() {
  console.log('generate');
}

cancl.addEventListener('click', () => {
  button.classList.toggle("h");
  cancl.classList.toggle("h");
  dateDiff = 0;
});
```

```css
.h {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="date-start">
<input type="date" id="date-end">
<button id="generate-report">Сгенерировать отчёт</button>
<button id="cancel" class="h">Отмена</button>
```

Comment: Если же отвечать непосредственно на заголовок вашего вопроса то легче всего добиться нужного результата используя XMLHttpRequest.abort() вместо fecth.then